# How can I concisely define a matrix-form partial derivative operator?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, vector-calculus, operators

I have a vector

$\boldsymbol{u}(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix} u_x(x,y) \\ u_y(x,y) \\ \end{bmatrix}.$

I would like to get

$\boldsymbol{\sigma}(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix} \sigma_x \\ \sigma_y \\ \tau_{xy} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial\:\! u_x}{\partial\:\! x} \\ \frac{\partial\:\! u_y}{\partial\:\! y} \\ \frac{\partial\:\! u_x}{\partial\:\! y} + \frac{\partial\:\! u_y}{\partial\:\! x} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial}{\partial\:\! x} & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{\partial}{\partial\:\! y} \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial\:\! y} & \frac{\partial}{\partial\:\! x} \end{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{u}\,.$

I have to write a slightly lengthy and repetitive code:

```
σ[u_] :=
{
  { D[u[[1]], x] } ,
  { D[u[[2]], y] } ,
  { D[u[[1]], y] + D[u[[2]], x] }
};
```

Is there are more concise way to achieve this?

Comment: `With[{ux = D[u[[1]], x], uy = D[u[[2]], y]},
 {{ux}, {uy}, {ux + uy}}]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you actually need to have a tensor rank of 2? this gives you a rank 1[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
U = {ux[x, y], uy[x, y]};
Append[Diagonal@Grad[U, {x, y}], Curl[{-1, 1} U, {x, y}]]
```

> {(ux^(1,0))[x,y],(uy^(0,1))[x,y],(ux^(0,1))[x,y]+(uy^(1,0))[x,y]}